# Get real IP from nginx stream

Tags: nginx

I have an nginx configuration as follow:

```
worker_processes 4;
worker_rlimit_nofile 40000;

events {
    worker_connections 8192;
}

stream {
    upstream rancher_servers_http {
        least_conn;
        server <node1>:80 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=5s;
        server <node2>:80 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=5s;
        server <node3>:80 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=5s;
    }
    server {
        listen     80;
        proxy_pass rancher_servers_http;
    }

    upstream rancher_servers_https {
        least_conn;
        server <node1>:443 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=5s;
        server <node2>:443 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=5s;
        server <node3>:443 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=5s;
    }
    server {
        listen     443;
        proxy_pass rancher_servers_https;
    }
}
```

But I would like to get the client real IP on requests. I've read https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/using-proxy-protocol/ and tried to update the 443 server as follow

```
server {
        listen     443 proxy_protocol;
        set_real_ip_from <ip of loadabalancer -> where nginx is installed>/24;
        proxy_pass rancher_servers_https;
    }
```

But when I try to get onto one of the site pointing to this loadbalancer I get a `PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR`.

I also tried to add `proxy_protocol on;` on the `server` section but I then get a `SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG`.

I'm a bit lost and don't know how to update my config in order to keep its currently working state and being able to retrieve the real client ip.

Thanks.

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_proxy_module.html#proxy_protocol

Answer (score 0):

```
    set_real_ip_from  192.168.0.0/24;
    real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;
    real_ip_recursive on;
```

Comment: doesn't this assume `http`, rather than `stream`?

Comment: yep, but seems me you are using http/https backends , why do you need stream? I think you can use server hosts directly.